# I'm trying to build a page with cards from a json but am getting one large cards, not individual ones

Tags: html, json

So I am a relative novice at this so please forgive me if I'm not using the right terminology.  Basically I have a json that has a lot of country data with travel regulations for covid.  I would like to set up a page with each country as it's own card (which has certain info on the card) Currently, the json is returning all fine, except the cards are not seperate - it's just one long card with all the info.  Below is the .js

```js
const url = '(the url to the json file)'
const output = document.querySelector('.output');
getData();

function getData() {
    fetch(url).then((res) => {
        return res.json()
    }).then((json) => {
        json.data.forEach(ele => {
            const title = document.createElement('div');
            title.innerHTML = `<h1>${ele.country}</h1>`
            title.style.background = ele.maincolour
            title.style.textIndent = "20px"
            title.style.paddingTop = "1px"
            output.append(title);
            const img1 = document.createElement('img');
            img1.src = ele.pod;
            title.style.background = ele.maincolour
            img1.style.width = "100%";
            title.append(img1);
            const body = document.createElement('div');
            body.innerHTML = `<b>Open For Tourists: </b><br>${ele.tourists}<br><br>
            <b>Vaccines Accepted:</b><br>${ele.vaccine}<br><br>
            <b>PCR Test: </b><br>${ele.pcr}<br><br>
            <b>Quarantine: </b><br>${ele.quarantine}<br><br>
            <b>Direct Flights: </b><br>${ele.directflights}`
            body.style.textIndent = "0px"
            body.style.fontFamily = 'Advent Pro, sans-serif'
            body.style.fontSize = "14px"
            body.style.paddingTop = "15px"
            body.style.paddingBottom = "20px"
            body.style.paddingLeft = "15px"
            title.append(body);
        })
    });
```

And below is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sheet Data</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="output">
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="output">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="output">
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="output">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure I've overlooked something super simple but like I said, I'm a massive novice (only been doing this for about a week).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: And what is`output` in: `output.append(title);` Add all relevant code. Also why dont you create whole card while you at it with column and card divs?

Comment: output is just what I've called the output from the querySelector.  

const url = '(the url to the json file'
const output = document.querySelector('.output');
getData();
function getData(){
    fetch(url).then((res)=>{
        return res.json()
    }).then((json)=>{

Like I said, I'm a novice, so I don't really know what you mean by "create whole card".  

Also forgot to mention that the page must also be dynamic as changes are happening sometimes hourly

Comment: Please edit and add that code in question, create [mre] with sample data of your response. Use <> button in editor to create snippet. And by create card I mean just like you create content title etc in your loop also create whole card inside it also and then append each card to row, dont hard code it in HTML.

Comment: OK thanks, that's a good idea - can you give me a sample of what creating a card in the javascript might look like?  I really have no idea.

Comment: Any chance of some help?  I'm seriously lost.  Even just a point in the right direction would be amazing :)

Comment: "can you give me a sample of what creating a card in the javascript might look like? I really have no idea. " how is this possible you literary did it numerous times yourself inside your forEach  loop? Is this even your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments I wrote:

If you want card to be made for each data in loop then remove all HTML beside row and create that `.column .card` structure in loop and appaned each card to `.row`....

So leave just this:

```
<div class="row">

</div>
```

and create this in js loop:

```
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="output">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

with:

```
// create your card structure 
      let column = document.createElement('div');
      column.classList.add("column");
      let card = document.createElement('div');
      card.classList.add("card");
      let output = document.createElement('div');
      output.classList.add("output");

      card.append(output)
      column.append(card)
      // now add your previus html into that card structure
      output.append(title)
      // add cards to row
      row.append(column);
```

```js
const url = '(the url to the json file)'
const row = document.querySelector('.row');
getData();

function getData() {
  fetch(url).then((res) => {
    return res.json()
  }).then((json) => {
    json.data.forEach(ele => {
      const title = document.createElement('div');
      title.innerHTML = `<h1>${ele.country}</h1>`
      title.style.background = ele.maincolour
      title.style.textIndent = "20px"
      title.style.paddingTop = "1px"
      const img1 = document.createElement('img');
      img1.src = ele.pod;
      title.style.background = ele.maincolour
      img1.style.width = "100%";
      title.append(img1);
      const body = document.createElement('div');
      body.innerHTML = `<b>Open For Tourists: </b><br>${ele.tourists}<br><br>
            <b>Vaccines Accepted:</b><br>${ele.vaccine}<br><br>
            <b>PCR Test: </b><br>${ele.pcr}<br><br>
            <b>Quarantine: </b><br>${ele.quarantine}<br><br>
            <b>Direct Flights: </b><br>${ele.directflights}`
      body.style.textIndent = "0px"
      body.style.fontFamily = 'Advent Pro, sans-serif'
      body.style.fontSize = "14px"
      body.style.paddingTop = "15px"
      body.style.paddingBottom = "20px"
      body.style.paddingLeft = "15px"
      title.append(body);


      // create your card structure 
      let column = document.createElement('div');
      column.classList.add("column");
      let card = document.createElement('div');
      card.classList.add("card");
      let output = document.createElement('div');
      output.classList.add("output");

      card.append(output)
      column.append(card)
      // now add your previus html into that card structure
      output.append(title)
      // add cards to row
      row.append(column);
    })
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

</div>
```